# Find a special number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, word-problem

Let's suppose there is a 2 digit number with both digits not the same and we reverse its digits order and then subtract from the original number and taking the absolute value of the difference obtained. Then is there a way to calculate for which number this difference is minimum.

And can there be a generalization for 3-digits numbers, 4-digits numbers and so on...?

Comment: If you are looking for numbers which are not zero, notice that $10a + b - (10b + a) = 9a-9b$ is a multiple of $9$... so every time you perform this operation with two-digit numbers you will always end up with some multiple of $9$.  Simple experimentation can reveal several examples of when you do end with exactly $9$.

Comment: @lulu ofcourse it would be zero haha.. I forgot to enter a important restriction.

Comment: Extending @JMoravitz's argument, you get  a multiple of $99$ with three digits.  It gets more interesting with four distinct digits.

Comment: For generalization to higher ordered numbers (*where we iterate just once*)... consider the examples of $\color{red}{3333}21\color{red}{3333}$ and $\color{red}{3333}2\color{red}{3}1\color{red}{3333}$ for inspiration.

Comment: @JMoravitz yes!! your observation is quite useful.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current answer does not answer OP's newly edited question, so I have decided to post a new answer.

Any 2-digit number can be expressed in the form $10a+b$ where $0\leq a, b<10$. Our final answer will be $(10a+b)-(10b+a)=9(a-b)$. Since $a\neq b$, $|9(a-b)|\geq9$. Any number satisfying $|a-b|=1$ works, like $10, 21, 34, $ etc.

If the question is generalised to a 3-digit number, any 3-digit number can be expressed in the form $100a+10b+c$ where $0\leq a, b, c<10$. Our final answer will be $(100a+10b+c)-(100c+10b+a)=99(a-c)$. Since, once again, $a\neq c$, $|99(a-c)|\geq99$. Any number satisfying $|a-c|=1$ works, like $130, 140, 768, $ etc.

Comment: If I continue more then for four digit numbers I need to think of a number abcd such that |a-d| and |b-c| both are equal to 1... Similarly we can find the maximum value of the difference by taking |a-c| = 9 (for three digit number) thanks I get it

Comment: Well that is not actually the case. For 4-digit numbers, $$\begin{align}&|(1000a+100b+10c+d)-(1000d+100c+10b+a)|\\&=|999(a-d)+90(b-c)|\\&\neq999|a-d|+90|b-c|\end{align}$$ In this case, the minimal value is achieved when $a-d=1$ and $b-c=-9$, which gives $|999\times1+90\times-9|=189$.

Comment: We want to minimise $|999(a-d)+90(b-c)|$, which is NOT the same as minimising $999|a-d|$ and $90|b-c|$. The process of thinking of the minimum is mostly intuitive, though, and there isn't really a fixed formula.

Comment: What do you mean? I did make a mistake but I edited it before you replied. Try refreshing your page?